# Facebook login button added exception in new SDK-4.0

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook sdk-4.0. when i added login button using below code.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/loginbyFacebookbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

But i am getting that exception. i've clean, add the library and build, restart eclipse Luna but getting error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.toRequestCode(CallbackManagerImpl.java:109)
at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<clinit>(LoginButton.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:442)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:194)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
```

please help me

Comment: Most of the times it is due to the fact that the dependencies have not been resolved. I don't have an idea of how dependencies can be added to a eclipse project

Comment: yes it may be. so we have not any other way for fixing it??

Comment: Is this only an issue in the editor view? the stack trace seems to imply that you can still build it and run it on a device?

Answer (score 0):

try FacebookSdk#sdkInitialize() method before view generate.

OK

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_s0010_toppage);
}
```

NG

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_s0010_toppage);
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());    
}
```